# Flex tree view with wrapped text on nodes

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, flex3, treeview, rendering

I've spend hours searching for a way to put one paragraph of text in one tree node in Adobe flex. How can I do it? I created a simple tree view but the text is cut after the right border.

So I tried to create a tree renderer. In the renderer I specified width=100 and the text wrapped. But the height of the nodes was not being calculated properly, so the text over consecutive nodes overlapped and got messed.

So how do i do wrapped text in a tree node?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[here](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/11/29/creating-a-flex-tree-control-with-variable-row-heights/) is your full solution, including runnable sample)

the hack is in:

```
<mx:Tree id="tree"
            dataProvider="{xmlDP}"
            labelField="@label"
            showRoot="false"
            variableRowHeight="true"
            wordWrap="true"
            alternatingItemColors="[#FFFFFF,#EEEEEE]"
            showScrollTips="true"
            width="300"
            rowCount="6" />
```